# Setting overflow:hidden correctly

Tags: html, css, overflow

this question arose from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335542/how-do-i-stretch-two-div-elements-to-fill-available-horizontal-space/4336185#4336185).

[This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GyxWm/5/) shows 1 outer and 5 inner div-elements.

How do I set `overflow:hidden;` in the e.g. last inner div-element with a sample `width:60px;` and a sample `height:44px;`?

Do you know why it is not working in my case?

Edit: Why do I have to use another div to set overflow:hidden [here](http://jsfiddle.net/GyxWm/7/)?

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using display: table-cell;

http://bytes.com/topic/html-css/answers/153857-how-can-i-force-clipping-text-table-cell

Comment: ok the conclusion of this url is: Wrap you content in another element. Not that easy to understand...

Answer (score 0):

thanks to @sunn0 I could understand that you must add a `<span>` for example, which will be compatible with `overflow:hidden;`

```
<div id="myid">
  <ul>
   <li><span class="content">my content</span></li>
   <li><span class="content">my other content</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

(In my example it was `<li>` that refused to hide the overflow)

```
#myid ul li{
    list-style-type: none;
    width: 110px; height: 20px;
    display: table-cell;
}

#myid ul li span.content{
    display: block;
    width: 110px; height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```