# How do I use JS to fill up availiable space?

Tags: javascript

I've been searching the www for a solution dealing with the question: How can I use screen.availWidth or something like it in the second inner div of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6fLDS/56/) to fill up the availiable space?
Is it possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Possible indeed: http://jsfiddle.net/6fLDS/57/

The required JS:

```
var _otherDivsTotalWidth = 100;
window.onload = function WindowLoad() {
    var oDiv = document.getElementById("test");
    if (oDiv)
        oDiv.style.width = (document.body.scrollWidth - _otherDivsTotalWidth -30) + "px";
}
```

This requires you to hard code the total width of the other DIV elements, it's possible to read that in code.. shouldn't be complicated  to add such thing to the above code.

Answer (score 1):

This migth be what you want :

```
<div style="position: relative;">
    <div style="position: absolute; width:50px;border:1px solid red;left: 0;">1</div>
    <div id="test" style="border: green 1px solid; margin: 0 50px;">2</div>
    <div style="position: absolute; width:50px;border:1px solid red;right: 0; top: 0;">3</div>
</div>
```

**Edit**: your problem looks like the 3-column layout : http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Three_Column_Layouts

Comment: Oh well, my html will be complex and believe me, I already tried to solve it with pure CSS. Unfortunatley it is not possible. I really need the JS way, but I'm not familar with it. That was the reason why I'm asking. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4335542/how-do-i-stretch-two-div-elements-to-fill-available-horizontal-space .There will be a more than 6 column layout. Never mind. Thank you ;-)